# How does GeoCoordinateWatcher choose its source?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, gps, windows-phone

I know that in the constructor of the GeoCoordinateWatcher object there is the possibility to specify the accuracy (default  or high), but for my university project I need to know more.

My professor asked me to search and specify also the algorithm or the heuristics used by the GeoCoordinateWatcher to choose his source.

I'm already aware of the MSDN article which says

Although the Location Service uses multiple sources of location information, and any of the sources may not be available at any given time (for example, no GPS satellites or cell phone towers may be accessible), the native code layer handles the work of evaluating the available data and choosing the best set of sources. All your application needs to do is to choose between high accuracy or the default, power-optimized setting. You can set this value when you initialize the main Location Service class, GeoCoordinateWatcher.

but I need to know more exactly how the native code layer handles the evaluation of the source.

Anyone can help me with this or point me to some more detailed article?

Comment: This is not a stack overflow question. This is a Programmers question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @madhukumar really, your answer is just the one I was looking for...seriously..have you even read the question??

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into the source code of the System.Device assembly (by using a decompiler like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)), you can see how it works.

In fact the [`GeoCoordinateWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx) is just a small wrapper that creates a COM object of type [`ILocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317674.aspx). This interface is part of the [Location API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464636.aspx), that Microsoft introduced with Windows 7. This itself is a part of the [Sensor API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318953.aspx), that also started with Windows 7.

If you dig a little bit through this documenation, you'll find this [introduction article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318936.aspx), which describes how this API works. One sentence within this introductions is:

> Sensor manufacturers can create device drivers to connect sensors with
>   Windows 7. Sensor device drivers are implemented by using the Windows
>   Portable Devices (WPD) driver model, which is based on the Windows
>   User Mode Driver Framework (UMDF).Many device drivers have been
>   written by using these frameworks.

So the manufacturers of GPS devices will provide a windows driver that will be installed on a system. This driver will announce itself as a location device to the system.

When you create a `GeoCoordinateWatcher` it asks through the location api for the desired data. The operation system checks which drivers have announced itself for being capable and starts these drivers. These drivers will then open the connection to the device, reading the data and forward it to the desired consumers.